# A Question About Recursive Functions

Tags: computability, recursion, turing-machines

We want to find a recursive function $f(x,y)$ in order to have this equality:

$$ \mathbf 
\varphi_{f(x,y)} = \varphi_x + \varphi_y$$

I know we should use "s-m-n" theorem, but I can't find the required function.
We be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the universel program $U(x,y)=\phi_x (y)$

From U, there is a program $\phi_p(x,y,z)=U(x,z)+U(y,z)$

Now, consider $f(x,y)=s_1^2(p,x,y)$
$$\forall z \quad\phi_{f(x,y)}(z)=\phi_p(x,y,z)=\phi_x (z)+\phi_y(z)$$

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how we're sure there is such a program from U, you mentioned in the second line?

Comment: @Aref because to get $\phi_p$ from $U$ I used only addition (a recursive operation) and composition.